# How do I use windows large pages in code?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, huge-pages

If we enable large pages, does the OS take advantage of it for me, or do I have to change our code?  For instance, can I expect HeapAlloc to use large pages under the hood?

I should add that we are using 64 bit windows server 2008.

Comment: How many areas with `MEM_LARGE_PAGES` are you going to use, do you really want to *manage* them non-trivially? If it's just once per program run, use `VirtualAlloc` and be sure you get what you want (there is no official answer on `HeapAlloc` as far as I know).

Comment: Let's say I have a program that uses about 4GB of ram during a transaction.  In a single transaction, we do millions of allocations through HeapAlloc or OpenFileMapping.  What I was wondering is...do I have to change the code to use the Large Pages explicitly?

Comment: I can change the HeapAlloc code to be an arena allocator that uses VirtualAlloc.  The OpenFileMapping is a bit of an issue though, since most of the files are small.  I think a number of files are open for a short span of time, so I could map them into 4mb pages even though it wasted most of that RAM.  I am trying to determine if there is a way to reserve a 4MB page, then tell OpenFileMapping to use a region within that RAM.  That way I could avoid most of the waste.

Comment: `HeapAlloc` will not use `MEM_LARGE_PAGES` memory. It always uses regular pageable memory.